# Covariance of two column matrices

Tags: random-variables, covariance, random-matrices

Let $X=\begin{bmatrix}
         x_{1} \\
         x_{2} \\
        \end{bmatrix}$ and $Y=\begin{bmatrix}
         y_{1} \\
         y_{2} \\
         \end{bmatrix}$ be two random variables.

Also let $B=\begin{bmatrix}
    ax_{1}+by_{1}\\ 
    ax_{2}+by_{2} 
    \end{bmatrix}$ where $a$ and $b$ are constants.

I tried to find the $Cov(X,B)$ and the following is the thing that I got.

$Cov(X,B)=E([X-E(X)][B-E(B)]^T)$

$=E\Bigg[\Bigg(\begin{bmatrix}
         x_{1} \\
         x_{2} \\
        \end{bmatrix}-E\begin{bmatrix}
         x_{1} \\
         x_{2} \\
        \end{bmatrix}\Bigg)\Bigg(\begin{bmatrix}
    ax_{1}+by_{1}\\ 
    ax_{2}+by_{2} 
    \end{bmatrix}-E\begin{bmatrix}
    ax_{1}+by_{1}\\ 
    ax_{2}+by_{2} 
    \end{bmatrix}\Bigg)^T\Bigg]$ .....$(1)$

Since $B=a[X]+b[Y]$, $(1)$ can be written as

$=E\Big[\Big(X-E(X)\Big)-\Big[\Big(a(X)+b(Y)\Big)-E\Big(a(X)+b(Y)\Big)\Big]^T\Big]$

$=E\Big[\Big(X-E(X)\Big)-\Big[\Big(a(X)-aE(X)\Big)+\Big(b(Y)-bE(Y)\Big)\Big]^T\Big]$

$=E\Big[\Big(X-E(X)\Big)-\Big[a\big((X)-E(X)\big)+b\big((Y)-E(Y)\big)\Big]^T\Big]$

I need to further simplify this expression. But I'm having a difficulty in proceeding further at this place.Can someone please give me some hints to do this?

Cheers,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that you've added a minus sign
$$E\Big[\Big(X-E(X)\Big)\color{red}-\Big[\Big(a(X)+b(Y)\Big)-E\Big(a(X)+b(Y)\Big)\Big]^T\Big]$$
and instead you should have
$$E\Big[\Big(X-E(X)\Big)\Big[\Big(a(X)+b(Y)\Big)-E\Big(a(X)+b(Y)\Big)\Big]^T\Big]$$
$$=E\Bigg[\Big(X-E(X)\Big)\Big[a\big((X)-E(X)\big)^T+b\big((Y)-E(Y)\big)^T\Big]\Bigg]$$
$$=E\Bigg[a\big(X-E(X)\big)\big((X)-E(X)\big)^T+b\big(X-E(X)\big)\big((Y)-E(Y)\big)^T\Big]\Bigg]$$

or using some properties of Cov:
$$\text{Cov}[X,aX+bY]=\text{Cov}[X,aX]+\text{Cov}[X,bY]=a\text{Cov}[X,X]+b\text{Cov}[X,Y].$$

Comment: Thanks, Matt!! I understood that..:)